# Copy files with particular string non zero batch

Tags: windows, logging, batch-file

I'm trying to copy all the logs that have a non-zero value on a certain string (can be in different lines) to be copied to a folder. Right now I a batch file that can copy based on a set value, I want it to be copied for any non-zero value. What do I need to modify to copy only files of non-zero. Maybe set the string to search for the zero "Errors 0" and if found don't copy.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.LOG) do (
   set found=false
   for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%b in ('find "Errors 1" "%%a"') do (
      if "!found!"=="false" (
         echo %%a >>output.txt
     copy %%a %OLDDIR%\output\sv1
         set found=true
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo on &setlocal
for %%a in (*.LOG) do (
    find "Errors 0" "%%~a" || copy "%%~a" "%OLDDIR%\output\sv1"
)
```

`||` if fail, process the next command
`&&` if success, process the next command